# Multiple instances of CMMotionManager, determining update interval

Tags: ios, core-motion

According to Apple's documentation for CMMotionManager, "An app should create only a single instance of the CMMotionManager class. Multiple instances of this class can affect the rate at which data is received from the accelerometer and gyroscope."

I have created a singleton to encapsulate this, but what I'm wondering is how should I handle the update interval. If each consumer of the manager needs to have a different update interval for the device motion updates, how do you handle them? My initial thought is to set it to the fastest update interval provided, and fallback to the next fastest as users are removed (stop observing motion updates), but this could lead to issues if a specific consumer needs to have a certain interval set.

Has anyone run into this issue? If so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have used multiple motion-manager in past in a single app, it doesn't effects the app performance drastically. However, if it effects the real time app behaviour/performance, I would set the motion-manager at highest required frequency but forward the motion-data to the consumers at their requested rates.

Requesting motion-data in high frequency doesn't have noticeable effect on cpu usage or battery, what will effect battery cpu/battery usage is the amount post-processing you do after each motion-update.

*Source: Personal experience, I've being working on an app which is in production for last 5 years, that app predicts user behaviour using device motion data.*

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I ended up going with. I was just wondering how people would handle it if a specific class needed a specific interval to operate properly.

Comment: @stealthdyno To paraphrase Beyonce, _"if you liked it, then you should have put a check-mark on it "_